# Performance difference between submitted and live app package

Tags: performance, windows-phone-8, jit

I wonder whether there is a performance difference between the .xap package i submitted to the windows phone store and the one served to the end users finally. I am asking because in the book "Windows Phone 8 Development Internals" there is something like

> "In Windows Phone 8, this process changes, such that all apps are
>   precompiled as part of the Windows Phone Store submission process.
>   This means that when a user downloads an app from the Windows Phone
>   Store, the app package already contains code that is compiled for ARM.
>   Because no “JITing” is required when the app is starting up or
>   running, users should experience faster app load times and improved
>   runtime performance"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test the app on the same conditions as the store (and using the same kind of pre-JITing), you just have to follow those steps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj585401(v=vs.105).aspx

In a nutshell: either start the app without the debugger attached, or uncheck the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" in the project properties.

Note that it will work only on a device, not in the emulator (which isn't a reliable way to measure performance anyway).

Source: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Compile-in-the-Cloud.aspx (section "More Details")